# Connecting Macbook Air 2011 to HP LP2475w monitor.. use DVI, HDMI or Display Port?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

The [HP LP2475w](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/382087-382087-64283-72270-3884471-3648442.html) supports all of the following inputs:

> DVI-I, HDMI, DisplayPort, Component Video, S-Video, and Composite Video

Which one is the preferred to connect the Macbook Air's mini-display port to?

Comment: I tried connecting a HP LP2475w to my macbook air 2011 using the Thunderbolt->DVI adaptor and that did not work. I never managed to get a picture on the screen all though the mac told me there was a screen attached...

Comment: HDMI works just fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I have this monitor since 2008. My experience with a MacBook Pro 13" (early 2011) is:

**HDMI**

Any cable will do it, but you'll have to override the Mac OS X settings to force RGB mode. To do that follow the instructions in

http://ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor

**DVI**

No problem, but only with Apple's official adaptor + DVI to DVI cable. In this case, image quality is perfect and I haven't got issues waking from sleep. I also tried with a 43€ mini DisplayPort to DVI 1m cable from Clicktronic and I saw random red and green pixels on dark areas of the screen. I also observed this issue with another mini DisplayPort to DVI cable from a different (cheaper) manufacturer.

**DisplayPort**

Using CA's mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable I have extremely annoying jitters and shakes on the screen. In between those, the image quality is perfect but overall renders the usage annoying. It looks like it gets better as the monitor stays turned on for some time (about an hour). I've also observed issues when waking from sleep. Apparently the problem is not the cable, and reports of good compatibility do exist.

http://estore.circuitassembly.com/products/mini-displayport-to-displayport-adapter-cable-1m.html

Comment: I wish I could give this ten upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Air (2010) had problems with this monitor connecting to the displayport on the monitor. (No problems with HDMI or DVI adaptors though.) Fonts are not rendered correctly - it's as though the MBA thinks it's a VGA or something and the fonts come out sort of chunky. The Mac Mini (2010) has the same problem. The problems on the mac side - other machines I've tried with displayport worked fine. I would have reservations as to whether Apple has fixed the problem in the 2011 macs.

Comment: Source? (......)

Answer (score 0):

Great question and great monitor.

Here is my order of preference:

- DisplayPort - native to the notebook and monitor. Just get a DisplayPort to MiniDisplayPort cable and you're set.
- HDMI - Preferred over DVI, because it has HDCP.
- DVI - Last choice.

The rest options are not recommended.

Comment: I've been looking for mini displayport to display port cable without luck. Do they exist?

Comment: @randomguy [6ft DisplayPort Male to Mini DisplayPort Male 32AWG Cable (Gold Plated Connectors)](http://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-32AWG-Cable-Plated-Connectors/dp/B0034X6SCY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310554840&sr=8-1) at Amazon looks good.

Comment: @randomguy Note that there are some bad reviews of this particular cable. More research is needed.

Comment: @randomguy I would go with [6ft 32AWG DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort Cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606&p_id=6007&seq=1&format=2) from Monoprice (which is my preferred source for cables and adapters; cheap and reliable). Good reviews for use with MacBook Pro (presumably the Air will be similar). Other lengths (3, 10, 15 feet) are also available.

Comment: @randomguy I am one of the people who *wrote* the negative reviews of that particular cable. It caused me endless problems with my Mac Pro and Dell Ultrasharp. I ended up going with a similar cable from http://www.circuitassembly.com/, which was well regarded on the MacRumors forums, and couldn't be happier with it.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayPort is the preferred way.

Comment: You've got me curious: Why? Do you have any info to back that up?